# Weird NavigationView Checkable behavior

Tags: android, navigationview

This is my menu xml file

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="ng.edu.binghamuni.bhu.ui.activity.HomeActivity">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item_today"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_schedule_black_48dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/today"
        app:showAsAction="never" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item_classes"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_chrome_reader_mode_black_48dp"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_classes"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</group>


<item
    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_settings"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_48dp"
    android:orderInCategory="200"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_logout"
    android:checkable="false"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_48dp"
    android:orderInCategory="500"
    android:title="@string/logout"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
```

I use the Settings item to navigate to another activity and the Logout Item for Logging out (Obviously) and that's why i dont want them checked but it turns out Settings gets check and when i navigate to the Settings activity and come down the back stack the settings Item is checked.

Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Comment: can u show your navigation click listener ..?

Comment: When I try your menu file with my NavigationView it's not happening what you are asking in your question. and I think you should have to try `app:checkable="false"` rather then `android:checkable="false"`...

Comment: Thanks. Let me try that.

Comment: No resource identifier found for attribute 'checkable' in package

Comment: I dont know whats the issue but your XML run on my side perfectly

Comment: Did you open a new activity with the settings item?

Comment: I get the same behavior I think. Did you solve this yet? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31636456/navigationview-has-erratic-behavior-with-selection

Answer (score 1):

```
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_today"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_schedule_black_48dp"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/today"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_classes"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_chrome_reader_mode_black_48dp"
            android:orderInCategory="100"
            android:title="@string/action_classes"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_settings"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_black_48dp"
            android:orderInCategory="200"
            android:title="@string/action_settings"
            app:showAsAction="never" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/drawer_item_logout"
            android:checkable="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_exit_to_app_black_48dp"
            android:orderInCategory="500"
            android:title="@string/logout"
            app:showAsAction="never" />
    </group>
```

You need to add the 'checkableBehavior' to the second group of items.